# A is x% more than B

Tags: contest-math, education, percentages, ratio

I am taking the AMC10 test, and I don’t want to lose points on silly misunderstandings. When a question says *“A is x% greater/less than B”*, or things like that sometimes with money, **which respect should we take if it doesn’t tell me which?** And please write a formula to make it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are given that a quantity $A$ is $x\%$ greater or less than $B$ the first thing is that the comparision is done with respect to the quantity $B$.

Look it in another way. So how do you calculate the $\%$ increase or decrease in a quantity with respect to another quantity.

If it is said that the quantity $A$ is $x\%$ greater  than quantity $B$ what you mean is : $$\frac{A-B}{B}=\frac{x}{100}$$
And if the quantity is $x\%$ less than $B$ then :
$$\frac{B-A}{B}=\frac{x}{100}$$
Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but, I guess, a statement like "$A$ is $x\%$ greater than B" formulaically should be interpreted as follows:

$$
A=B+\frac{B}{100}\cdot x=B\left(1 + \frac{x}{100}\right)
$$

Likewise, "$A$ is $x\%$ less than B" should be understood like this:

$$
A=B-\frac{B}{100}\cdot x=B\left(1 - \frac{x}{100}\right)
$$

So, I guess you could say you're calculating percents with respect to $B$.

Comment: I would rather see $A = B + (x/100)B$ so that the "per cent" modifies $x$. Even better is $A = (1 + x/100)B$.

Comment: Well, it's not hard to get those after some rather very basic algebraic manipulations. Thanks.

Comment: They are algebraically equivalent but one reflects the semantics better.

Comment: When I think of something like $10\%$ of $X$, I immediately divide $X$ by $100$ and then multiply the result by $10$. Because $10\%$ of $X$ is nothing more than $10$ pieces out of the $100$ pieces that you get when $X$ is divided by $100$. But that's just me.